# How to remove NotReady nodes from kubernetes cluster automatically

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running the kuberenets cluster on bare metal servers and my cluster nodes keep added and removed regularly. But when a node is removed, kubernetes does not remove it automatically from nodes list and **kubectl get nodes** keep showing NotReady nodes. Is there any automated way to achieve this? I want similar behavior for nodes as kubernetes does for pods.

Comment: I believe that the [cluster-autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/cluster-autoscaler-1.14.2/cluster-autoscaler#readme) does that, so you might try running it or look around in the source and see how to make your own controller which does the same thing

Comment: which pod network add-on are you using?

Answer (score 7):

To remove a node follow the below steps

```
Run on Master
# kubectl cordon <node-name>
# kubectl drain <node-name> --force --ignore-daemonsets  --delete-emptydir-data
# kubectl delete node <node-name>
```

Comment: I need some automated way similar to POD eviction in kubernetes.

Comment: Doing this in an automated manner: eventually, some network outage or other temporary failure could lead to your script removing nodes that actually work. Containers unable to restart after a drain, lacking compute resources. Cluster autoscaler are supposed to remove the appropriate node entries after scaling down.

Comment: drain's first step is to cordon, at least in more modern versions so that isn't important anymore. Also, I'd avoid the --force as a default as it could cause a brief outage. I'd rather fail and investigate what workload may need a graceful move.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this little bash command, or set it as a cron-job.

```
kubectl delete node $(kubectl get nodes | grep NotReady | awk '{print $1;}')
```